# Static classes vs class member access on instantiation

Tags: php, object, global, static-methods, instantiation

In versions of PHP prior to 5.4 I used static classes to instantiate an object and immediately call the required function, for example:

```
$result = Foo::init()->bar();
```

In the above example, the static function `init()` simply instantiates the class in which it is contained and returns it as an object. This provides method chaining functionality and allows me to immediately call `bar()`, all in one line of code. The static function `init()` looks something like this:

```
static public function init() {
   $object = new self();
   return $object;
}
```

Now PHP 5.4 has added support for class member access on instantiation, and instead of using a static class I can now do the following:

```
$result = (new Foo)->bar();
```

**My question:** Is my old way of using static classes bad, and if so, why? Now that PHP supports class member access on instantiation, is this the more correct way of accessing class members immediately after object instantiation?

Comment: Why do you write a class when you need a function? - And probably both are equally bad: You should have two piles of objects: Those that take care to instantiate others, and those that don't care.

Comment: The code I provided in my question was only a simple example to demonstrate the concept of what I'm talking about. Would you mind expanding a bit more on your comment on two piles of objects?

Comment: Take a look here: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/ , there is also a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc - The two piles of objects is around minute 24 or so, but the whole video is worth to watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's all your `->init()` does, you can get away with `(new Foo)->bar();`, but when you go the Dependancy Injection route, you most likely want to create some kind of Factory to 'inject those depedencies' on instantiation. The factory may a full fledged instantiated object, or just a static method for starters, but fact of the matter is: if you need outside access injected into your class (database handlers, settings) now or possibly in the future, and you *don't* want to abuse globals or singletons (which are kind of globals...), you'll be very thankfull you have 1 method / class where your objects are instantiated rather then sprinkled through the codebase.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the new way is more correct, so use it if you're able. The way you had it before isn't "bad", though; it's a clean, simple solution to a frustrating problem.